# i couldn't type in an element using cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to fill passwords fields in sign up form using cypress, but it doesn't work with me
my code:

```
describe("SignUP", function(){

it('OpenSignuoForm',function(){
cy.visit('https://mawadda-eg.com')
cy.get('.tt-tools-button').click();
cy.get('#header > div > nav > div.tt-menu-collapse.tt-submenu-dark > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').click();
cy.get('#user_name').type('automation');
cy.get('#e_mail').type('moatazqc+100@gmail.com');
cy.get('#password').type('test');
})    
})
```

Comment: here is the error  i have got  Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.type() failed because this element is not visible:

Comment: Is the element visible? How do you verify that it is actually visible and that your selectors work? Do you have typos in your selectors, considering that "OpenSignuoForm" already contains one"

Answer (score 0):

After checking the website attached , It didn't work because that id is duplicated, use another css selector , or locate with XPath  with this locator `(//input[@id='password'])[1]`

**Detailed Answer for using XPath locators in cypress.**

In cypress the default locator strategy is using the CSS-Selectors using the normal `cy.get()` , but if we would like we can also locate elements using the XPath plugin https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath .

**How to install and use it**

1. install it with yarn `yarn add cypress-xpath --dev`
2. Then include in the project support file  `cypress/support/index.js` as

```js
require('cypress-xpath')
```

3. Use it in any `it` test with `cy.xpath()` and you can chain it same as you chain `cy.get()`

so the final code you can locate and type on the element in the question should be

```js
cy.xpath("(//input[@id='password'])[1]").type("test");
```

Comment: please provide me with the exact command

Comment: If you would like to use XPath , you can install `xpath` plugin first, then use the locator `(//input[@id='password'])[1]` , let me add details to my answer for that

Comment: Thanks dear . it works with me now

Comment: @MoatazSelim appreciate Marking my answer as the correct answer since it did help :D